# will nodejs global variables lead memory leak?

Tags: node.js, react-native

I notice react native demo code always show below usage.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
// ... some styles
});
```

I'm newbie that don't deeply understand memory management of GC, but if in above way, will variable `styles` be freed? if so, when?

I think this `styles` is global variable in this module, and I'm not sure that whether do below method maybe better..

```
this.styles = StyleSheet.create();  // in the module.exports
```

will anybody provide any suggestions?

thanks for your time.

Comment: Neither of your examples are global variables, because they are local to the module. They will be freed when nothing references them anymore, if that ever happens.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara  thanks for your reply :)